# Integration and Euclidean geometry

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, definite-integrals, euclidean-geometry

What intrinsic relationship is there between (riemann) integration and Euclidean geometry that enables one to get area under the curve as a integral? This can only be related to the definition of riemann integral as a limit of sums of areas of rectangles; or is it something else.

Comment: Yes, that is only related to the definition of area of a rectangle as base x height. Change that definition, and you get another notion of area, but I'd better say **measure** instead. As José rightfully points out, you should read something about "measure theory" if you want to pursue this further. And as for non-Euclidean geometries, these amount to studying Riemannian manifolds with different metric tensors. A metric tensor induces a measure, and we're back to measure theory.

Comment: So basically it is because in our integration we are using the lebesgue measure and the lebesgue measure of a rectangle is length times breadth. Am I right?

Comment: Yes, more or less that's it, but without more study we cannot go farther.

Comment: Euclidean geometry is special, for example, in the following sense: if you zoom a non-Euclidean geometry, you get Euclidean geometry in the limit. It's basically the simplest geometry and many notions have interpretations in this geometry.

Answer (score 1):

The Riemann integral is defined in such a way (through a limit of sums of areas of rectangles, as you wrote) that the area under the curve of a non-negative function is equal to the integral of that function.

Comment: Is it possible to give a definition of integration with some other geometry then? If so, what is it called?

Comment: Yes, it is possible. That is done in the context of [measure theory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Measure_(mathematics)).

Comment: Can you give a concrete example for me to look up? The area under the curve should be the area under some non-Euclidean geometry and should be equal to the value of the integral.

Answer (score 1):

Reffer to *method of indivisibles* by Bonaventura Cavalieri (1598-1647). This method was used and learned at universities before the discovery of Riemannian integration

Answer (score 0):

A bit tongue-in-cheek, the intrinsic relationship can be seen as "Riemannian integration was constructed specifically for this connection to work the way it does."

Comment: Do analogous definitions of integration exist for non-Euclidean geometries?